# How to show laravel debugbar only to certain people?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. How can I display debugbar only for certain people?

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz 5.4

Comment: If you want to display the debugbar, set the `APP_DEBUG` to `true`, if you want to hide set `APP_DEBUG` to `false`.

Comment: @aceraven777 okey, I understand it. But, I need APP_DEBUG true only for 3 users, APP_DEBUG false for others. How can I do it?

Comment: How do you determine the 3 users? Via IP address or via logged in user?

Comment: Hope my answer below helps you.

Comment: @aceraven777 thanks for your answer. Users I can determine by their ids, but when I try to use Auth class I get error ReflectionException in Container.php line 721: Class hash does not exist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the documentation here: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

If you want to enable/disable debugbar at runtime, use this codes:

```
\Debugbar::enable();
\Debugbar::disable();
```

You may do something like this. Create a middleware `php artisan make:middleware TestMiddleware`, Don't forget to edit `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add `TestMiddleware`

```
protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\TestMiddleware::class,
        ...
    ];
```

Then this is your `TestMiddleware.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class TestMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->user() && in_array(auth()->id(), [1,2,3])) {
            \Debugbar::enable();
        }
        else {
            \Debugbar::disable();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: ReflectionException in Container.php line 721: Class hash does not exist

Comment: My bad, I edited my answer, try putting it in `boot` method

Comment: auth()->user() is NULL

Comment: Hi @TheWorldNode, undo your changes in `AppServiceProvider`, sorry didn't know that putting it on `AppServiceProvider` won't work. I put the code via middleware instead. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Hi. Faced such a problem, that many requests executes before debugbar enables in middleware)))

Comment: How can you tell that it executes requests before middleware?

Comment: dd(  auth()->check() ,auth()->user() ) ;
false , null

Comment: You should also create «[Fallback Route](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#fallback-routes)». Add to `/routes/web.php` this: `Route::fallback(function () {return view("404");});` (and create `404.blade.php` view). Without this "error404" pages will not use middlewares — you will see debugbar on them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in this in Your `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider as Bry;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {


    }
   public function register(){

      if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'YourIp'){
         $this->app->register(Bry::class); // or $this->app->register(new  Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider()); 
       }

   }
```

By this way you can register ServiceProvider dynamicaly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, with REMOTE_ADDR it works, but can I make a condition using GET parameters? For example, when I try to make such a condition: if ($_REQUEST["test"] === "y"){
            $this->app->register(Bry::class);
        } if falls with errors in console Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined and many others

Comment: @TheWorldNode Yess you can make it using $_GET too

Comment: Here is a fix to make it work properly:
`$this->app->register(new \Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider($this->app));`

Comment: You should use isset() also when using $_SERVER, since this variable is not always available or identical in all environments, and could cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for IP address to toggle it in `web.php`.

```
//Enabling DEBUGBAR in Production Only for developers
if(in_array(Request::ip(), [allowed IPs])) {
    config(['app.debug' => true]);
}
```